# Excluding one item from list (by Index), and take all others

Tags: c#, .net, linq, list, enumerable

There is a `List<int>` containing some set of numbers. Randomly I select an index, which will be processed separately (call it *master*). Now, I want to exclude this particular index, and get all other elements of `List` (call them *slave*).

```
var items = new List<int> { 55, 66, 77, 88, 99 };
int MasterIndex = new Random().Next(0, items .Count);

var master = items.Skip(MasterIndex).First();

// How to get the other items into another List<int> now? 
/*  -- items.Join;
    -- items.Select;
    -- items.Except */
```

`Join`, `Select`, `Except` - any of them, and how?

**EDIT:** Cannot remove any item from the original list, otherwise I have to keep two lists.

Comment: I know that this is an old question, but it may be worth considering replacing the terms "master" and "slave" - the tech industry in general is moving away from these terms due to their association with slavery. Some suggested alternatives: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Master/slave_(technology)#Possible_replacement_conventions

Comment: Fair point @Lou

Answer (score 44, accepted):

Use [Where](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb549418(v=vs.100).aspx):-

```
var result = numbers.Where((v, i) => i != MasterIndex).ToList();
```

Working [Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/Ee2sNK).

Comment: Lovely! It works flawlessly. This form of `Where` wasn't obvious anywhere in documentation.

Comment: @Ajay - Documentation is there, check the link I have shared for `Where`, its the second overload of Where.

Comment: Yeah. By this time, I have already utilized this approach in the actual product code (which isn't obviously list of ints).

Answer (score 4):

If performance is an issue you may prefer to use the [List.CopyTo](https://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/t69dktcd(v=vs.110).aspx) method like this.

```
List<T> RemoveOneItem1<T>(List<T> list, int index)
{
    var listCount = list.Count;

    // Create an array to store the data.
    var result = new T[listCount - 1];

    // Copy element before the index.
    list.CopyTo(0, result, 0, index);

    // Copy element after the index.
    list.CopyTo(index + 1, result, index, listCount - 1 - index);

    return new List<T>(result);
}
```

This implementation is almost 3 times faster than @RahulSingh answer.

Answer (score 3):

You could remove Master item from the list,

```
List<int> newList = items.RemoveAt(MasterIndex);
```

[RemoveAt()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5cw9x18z%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) removes the item from the original list, So it's not necessary to assign the collection to a new list. After calling RemoveAt(), `items.Contains(MasterItem)` would return `false`.

Comment: Requires two lists. I need to keep original!

Comment: @Ajay RemoveAt() removes the item from the original list, So it's not necessary to assign it to a new list. After calling RemoveAt() "items" will not have master item in it.

Comment: So, you want I should read from DB, network, file again? That is not appropriate.

Comment: @Ajay Just saw your edit that you dont want to remove item from original list.